# Are there reasons to skip the initialization of the for loop?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

For instance,

```
int i = 0;
for( ; i < 5; ++i )
{
    doStuff();
}
```

Versus

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
{
    doStuff();
}
```

The only time I have seen the first method is when the variable to be initialized is a really long named iterator. Is there anything performance wise that would make one more beneficial? Or is it merely choice and readability?

Comment: What if `i` is a parameter?

Comment: To pollute the enclosing scope with an unneeded variable and contribute to general confusion.

Comment: Also, the older C89 standard requires variables to be declared at the beginning of any block so the first way was the **only** way to do things. This constraint was alleviated as a part of a C99 extension.

Comment: In C89, it was common to do `int i; for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`, i.e. declare it outside the loop, initialize it inside the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason you might do this is because you need to know the value of the iterator/index after the loop has ended. That doesn't really make sense with your example, because you know the value will be `5`, but sometimes you do not know this in advance. Consider:

```
int i = 0;
for(; isStillOkay(i); ++i )
{
  doStuff();
}

// now we can use the final value of i for something
```

In general, the only reason you could have to do this is to make sure the iterator/index is available in the enclosing scope. If you don't need that, all you are doing is polluting that scope. As always, the advice is to give all objects the smallest scope necessary.

If you have long types, I recommend you use `auto` to deduce the types for you. If you don't have C++11 support, I then recommend the following formatting:

```
for (std::some::very_long<type>::name iterator_name = some_big_initializer;
     iterator_name < complicated && condition != iterator_name;
     ++iterator_name)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Of course this could also be written `int i; for (i = 0; isStillOkay(i); ++i) { doStuff(); } /* now we can use the final value of i for something */`, then the assignment is still in the `for`.

Comment: Thanks. The code I was looking at had it as the first method but I think it was for readability as it was in a small method and did nothing with the final value. My example is poor though and yours is what the code resembled.

Comment: @nwalsh Well I wouldn't suggest that for the sake of not polluting the scope. It's easy to make the `for` loop more readable by placing each of its parts on separate aligned lines.

Comment: It's also useful to pull out the initialization step when you have an end iterator you want to have a copy of before the loop in addition to the iterator you're using; this is also an issue mixing end and current iterators for const correctness reasons if you do it in the for loop initialization step. Sometimes you have multiple iterators as well, say you are considering pair-wise items. Sometimes you might maintain data of different types you can't initialize in the for loop, say an int and a float that are logically always the same value. To add a few more reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No need for initialization when you have a good reason for an infinite loop:

```
bool run(){
    for(;;){
        if(ERROR)
            break;
    }
}
```